# Import files into Visual Studio without drag and drop, is there any sdk to do this?

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2015, generator, code-generation

I have a code generator service that outputs files to a local share, which we use to drag and drop into Visual Studio 2015. The generation service uses T4 templates and it's a WCF service.

Our architectural design has become more complex and we need a way to add files into Visual Studio programmatically without dragging and dropping for each layer, as this is now affecting our productivity, besides a bug in Visual Studio that at times does not add the files, so we have to do the drag and drop twice.

Are there any SDK's, libraries or code that can do this? Another consideration is that we use TFS, so some files may be locked.

Comment: Too vague to give shopping advice, just write your own.  Create a VS add-in.

Answer (score 0):

[Project.ProjectItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.aspx) has multiple Add... methods, for example, AddFromFile. See [HOWTO: Create a project item from a Visual Studio add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014009.aspx) for a complete sample.